# Can't we really add together two points on a manifold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, reference-request, classical-mechanics

Let us consider a classical mechanical system with observables being smooth functions $C^\infty(X)$ on a Poisson manifold $X$. The algebra of observables will be denoted as $A$

Next we can define states as linear real-valued functions on this algebra of observables, [see an entry in nLab.](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/classical+mechanics#observables_and_states):

> A classical state is a linear function $\rho: A \to \mathbb R$
>
> - which is positive in that for all $a \in A$ we have that
> - and which is normalized in that $\rho(1) = 1$

Then it proceeds with the definition of pure state:

> a pure state is a state that is not only a linear map, but even an associative algebra homomorphism $\rho : A \to \mathbb R$.

After that a remarkable statement is made:

> If the classical mechanical system comes from a Poisson manifold
>   $(X,\{-,-\})$ ... then the pure states correspond precisely to the
>   points of the manifold $X$. So each point of $X$ is one specific (=
>   “pure”) state that the mechanical system defined by $(X,\{-,-\})$ can
>   be in, whereas a general state $\rho : A \to R$ is a distribution of
>   such specific states.

Unfortunately I could not find this statement in the references provided at nLab. Could anyone please suggest any sources to substantiate the claim above?

**What bothers me,** is that pure states being linear functions should admit an algebra structure with observable-wise addition and summation. Does it mean there is a natural algebra structure for the points of a manifold?

I was sure, that a sum of two points should not make sense, like [it was explained by Qiaochu Yuan in this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185326/14862)

As for additional sources, Peter Bongaarts's book *Quantum Theory. A Mathematical Approach* states that there exists

> ... a remarkable theorem, unfortunately in an
>   unpublished preprint, stating that two manifolds $\mathcal M_1$ and $\mathcal M_2$ are
>   diffeomorphic if and only if the corresponding algebras of functions
>   $C^\infty(\mathcal M_1)$ and $C^\infty(\mathcal M_2)$ are isomorphic,
>   and that moreover a manifold $\mathcal M$ can be reconstucted from its
>   function algebra $C^\infty(\mathcal M)$.

The book does not explain this "reconstruction". The unpublished preprint is Thomas, E.G.F.: *Characterization of a manifold by the $*$-algebra of its $C^\infty$ functions.* Preprint Mathematical Institute, University of Groningen, however there is apparently no easy access to this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, can you can - it's just that the sum of two "points", i.e., the sum of the pure states associated to two points, is not necessarily itself a ***pure*** state. As your excerpt says:

> ... whereas a general state $\rho:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is a distribution of such specific states.

So there is certainly not, in general, an addition operation on the points of the manifold *that produces a point on the manifold*.